# Unable to install apk file in my android mobile

Tags: android

This is py struggling about installation of apk file in my android phone.

I am using htc android phone in that i am trying to install my application.

I developed application using eclipse ADT plugin and taken apk file and copied in my phone SD card -> Android folder.

After that i installed Astro file manager in my phone and trying to browse my apk file but still i unable to find Android folder and my apk file in the Astro file manager.

I just stuck up there.

Can anybody fix my problem?

Thanks and Regards,

Py

Comment: You are not able to see the folder at all on the SD card?  Try checking permissions using the ADT plugin just to be sure.  Can you see the rest of your SD card?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but I've had the most success using the Linda file manager, that is an option too.

Comment: Can't help you with this, but I find easy to deploy apps on phone directly from Eclipse, see instruction on http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#deployondevice

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

Now I am able to find my apk file as it was copied in android folder in SD card

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps:

1. Connect your phone with your laptop and open `cmd`,
2. Locate `plaform-tools` in your `sdk` folder.
3. Run following command: `adb install -r <drag and drop your APK file>`

You will get the `SUCCESS!!` message on `cmd`, and your app is installed on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can also, save the .apk file in the platform-tools folder of your sdk, and simply run "adb install MyApp.apk" after changing directory to platform-tools.